# Lua request from Tado thermostat api

Tags: post, lua, token

I'm building a so called 'Quickapp' in Home Center 3 (From Fibaro) in the 'Lua' programming language. I want to fetch some data from the Tado api, but it's poorly documented. I keep getting the following message from the console:

> Full authentication is required to access this resourceunauthorized

I think that's because I need do assign the Bearer token from the request, but i'm a little lost how...

This is what i have so far:

```
function QuickApp:fetchTadoData(username,password,client_secret)


local url = "https://auth.tado.com/oauth/token"
  local postdata = {
        ["client_id"] = "tado-web-app",
        ["grant_type"] = "password",
        ["scope"] = "home.user",
        ["username"] = username, 
        ["password"] = password, 
        ["client_secret"] = client_secret
  }
  local extraheaders = {
        ["content-type"] = "application/json" 
  }
 
  self.http:request(url, {
    options={
      headers = extraheaders,
      data = json.encode(postdata),
      method = "POST"
    },
    success = function(status)
       self:debug(status.data)
    end,
    error = function(error)
       errorlog("Error getting data: "..error)
       self:debug("hallo")
    end
  })
end
```

I know the Curl code to get the 'Bearer token' response:

```
curl -s "https://auth.tado.com/oauth/token" -d client_id=tado-web-app -d grant_type=password -d scope=home.user -d username="you@example.com" -d password="Password123" -d client_secret=wZa
```

But I don't know how to translate this to the above Lua code. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

https://manuals.fibaro.com/home-center-3-quick-apps

Looks OK, the main thing I'm noticing is this:

> "self.http must have previously been created by net.HTTPClient"

```
function QuickApp :fetchTadoData( username, password, client_secret )
  self .http = net .HTTPClient( { timeout = 5000 } )  --  5 seconds

  local url = "https://auth.tado.com/oauth/token"
 
  local requestBody = {
      action = 'create',
      params = {
          ["client_id"] = "tado-web-app",
          ["grant_type"] = "password",
          ["scope"] = "home.user",
          ["username"] = username, 
          ["password"] = password, 
          ["client_secret"] = client_secret
      }
  }

  local extraheaders = {
        ["content-type"] = "application/json",
        ["accept"] = "application/json" 
  }

  self .http :request( url, {
    options = {
      headers = extraheaders,
      data = json .encode( requestBody ),
      method = "POST"
    },

    success = function( response )
       self :debug( response .status )
       self :debug( response .data )
    end,  --  success

    error = function( msg )
       self :debug( 'Error: ' ..msg )
    end  --  error
  })
end  --  :fetchTadoData()
```